# How to add a Comment to an entity in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the scenario dumbed down:

I have a class `Device`

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[MaxLength(50)]
public String Name { get; set; }
[Required]
public Category Category { get; set; }
[Required]
public Manufactor Manufactor { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }
```

And a class `Comment`

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public string Author { get; set; }
public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
```

As you can see an entity of device can have many comments, but one comment only has one device.

In my controller I have these two actions:

```
    public ActionResult AddComment(int id)
    {
        Device device = db.Devices.Include(x => x.Comments).Where(dev => dev.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (device == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(device);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("CommentAdded")]
    public ActionResult CommentAdded(int id)
    {
        Device device = db.Devices.Find(id);
        db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Devices.AddOrUpdate(device);

        foreach(var comment in device.Comments)
        {
            db.Comments.AddOrUpdate(comment);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Up to this point everything seemed straight forward. But suddently I don't know how to create a view in which I can do these 3 things:

1. Display Name of the device
2. Display all comments
3. Display a textfield to add another comment

I can easily achieve 1 and 2 but I have no idea on how to add another comment and then submit the form.

AddComment.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Device</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)

            </div>
            @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => comment.Author)
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => comment.DateCreated)
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => comment.Content)
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The problem at hand is: what do I need to change in my view (pos. controller), to be able to add another comment to the device selected?

Comment: Related to the code but not the crux of the question: Be careful with the use of AddOrUpdate on the DbSets in your context. This extension method was really intended for migrations and doesn't always behave as you'd expect outside of the area of seeding.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines. Just need create a html form and map the form fields to the ajax function. then call the function when the form is submitted.

hopefully that helps.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddComment(int id,Comment comment)
{
    Device device = db.Devices.Find(id);
    comment.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    Device.Comment.Add(comment);
    db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.saveChanges();


    return Json("Success");
}


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AddComment",
        data: { Id: '@Html.IdFor(m => m.Id)', 
        Comment: { Content: 'data',    Author: 'Author'} },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
        if (data == "Success") {
           $('#COMMENTSDIV').append(" YOUR COMMENTS MARKUP HERE ");
            }
        }
       });
```

Comment: can we keep it straight up Razor-syntax / js-free please?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the add comment functionality in the form and post that back to the server with a corresponding action.  That action can return the entire view with the new comment added if you would like.